# G++ stack smashing detected

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели, g++

Передо мной стоит задача обернуть значения массива, для решения этой задачи я воспользовался сдвигом указателей на значения элементов массива.

```
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test[6];
    int* beg = test;
    int* end = test + sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test) - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i)
        {
      test[i] = i*2;
      }
     while(beg <= end)
       {
        //swap(&end,&beg);
    *beg ^= *end ^= *beg ^= *end;
    beg++;end--;
    }
 for(const int* p = test; p < test + sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test); p++)
   {
     cout << *p <<endl;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Программа компилируется успешно и на экран выводится обернутый массив, но возникает ошибка stack smashing detected, как это возможно устранить ?

И при использовании функции **swap( )** из библиотеки **alghorithm** как правильно передавать в нее указатели, чтобы их обмен выполнялся верно?

Comment: Сколько у вас элементов в массиве `int test[6];`? Шесть. А со сколькими вы работаете? `for(int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i)` С семью :( И еще - формально `*beg ^= *end ^= *beg ^= *end;` не очень хорошо, хак... А еще - зачем вам менять элемент с самим собой? (`while(beg <= end)`)? Тут просто `<` было бы логичнее и вернее - если `beg == end`, получается ерунда.

Comment: Да, действительно,  что-то я поторопился спрашивать )

Comment: this: `for(int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i)`  is beyond end of array `test[]`  Suggest: `for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)`  Note: removed `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сколько у вас элементов в массиве `int test[6];`? Шесть. А со сколькими вы работаете? `for(int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i)`? С семью :(

И еще - формально `*beg ^= *end ^= *beg ^= *end;` не очень хорошо, хак...

А еще - зачем вам *пытаться* менять элемент с самим собой? (`while(beg <= end)`)? Тут просто `<` и логичнее и вернее - когда `beg == end`, получается ерунда.

Словом, я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    int test[7];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i)
    {
        test[i] = i*2;
    }

    int* beg = test;
    int* end = test + sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test) - 1;

    while(beg < end) swap(*beg++,*end--);

    for(const int* p = test; p < test + sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test); p++)
    {
        cout << *p <<endl;
    }
}
```

Впрочем, нет, соврал! я бы делал так:

```
reverse(test, test+7);
```

:)